# Solve the following equation: $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I solve the following equation:

$z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$

Comment: Is $z\in \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: This is $(z^5-1)/(z-1)$ for $z\neq 1$.

Comment: Look up roots of unity

Comment: Please include your try to solving this equation

Comment: These are the nth roots of unity or 1. How come this is tagged as *real-analysis* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is well known that $z^n-1=(z-1)(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} z^i)$. Substituting $n=5$ gives us $z^5-1=(z-1)(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4)$. Thus, we have the following:

$$1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4=\frac{z^5-1}{z-1} \ (z \neq 1)$$

The right side of the equation is $0$ only when the numerator $z^5-1=0$ and $z \neq 1$. Thus, we must solve the equation $z^5=1$ when $z \neq 1$, which is just the complex fifth [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

By [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Examples), we know these roots of unity are $\cos \frac{2n\pi}{5}+i\sin \frac{2n\pi}{5}$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. However, if $n$ is $0$, then this number equals $1$, which can not be a solution. Also, if $n < 0$ or $n \geq 5$, then we can take the modulo of $n$ by $5$ to find an equivalent solution as adding or subtracting $n$ by $5$ simply adds or subtracts the angle by $2\pi$, which does not change the answer. Thus, $1 \leq n \leq 4$ and the solution set is $\{\cos \frac{2n\pi}{5}+i\sin \frac{2n\pi}{5} : n \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}\}$

Comment: @SBareS You're right; I forgot the $i$s. I've edited my answer to include the $i$s. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 3):

Hint about how to calculate $\sin(2\pi n/5)$, $\cos(2\pi n/5)$: using well know trigonometric formulas,
$$2\cos^2(\pi/5) - 1 = \cos(2\pi/5) = -\cos(3\pi/5) = -(4\cos^3(\pi/5) - 3\cos(\pi/5)),$$
i.e., $t = \cos(\pi/5)$ is a root of
$$4t^3 + 2t^2 -3t - 1 = (t + 1)(t - (1+\sqrt5)/4)(t - (1-\sqrt5)/4),$$
and the only positive root of this polynomial is $\cos(\pi/5) = (1+\sqrt5)/4$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $5$-th root of unity. Then the equation has exactly the four roots $\zeta,\zeta^2,\zeta^3,\zeta^4$, because of
$$
\frac{z^5-1}{z-1}=z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1.
$$

Comment: Okay so we get $z^5$=1 and $z$ not 0. How do I find the 5-th roots of the unity?

Comment: @theophileveto I've edited my answer to answer that part.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=z+z^4$. Then (using $z^5=1$) $u^2=z^2+2z^5+z^8=z^2+z^3+2$. Hence $u^2+u=-1$. You can solve this quadratic for $u$ and then use $zu=z^2+z^5=z^2+1$ to find a quadratic in $z$ that you can solve.

Answer (score 2):

$$ z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1= \frac{1-z^5}{1-z}=0 $$

On the Argand diagram rotate about origin the unit vector $ 1 + 0 i $ five times through angle $ 2 \pi/5. $ The tips of the unit radius vector are  roots of the given equation, the fifth roots of unity.